# How to solve unresolved external symbol error - if_nametoindex in visual studio 2013

Tags: c

```
struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr;
server_addr.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex(p_global->ini_params.remote_nw_type);
```

This is the code line that is generating the error. I am working on ipv6. Please tell if there's a library that's missing for this or something else.

What on earth is `if_nametoindex` is doing and what value is desired for `sin6_scope_id`?

Comment: [Somthing to start with...](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nametoindex).

Comment: you are trying to compile code written for linux on windows. good luck, you will need it.

Answer (score 1):

This function was introduced in Windows Vista. Just add Iphlpapi.lib to your dependencies list. It works for me while compiling libtorrent project with BOOST_NO_ANSI_APIS preprocessor directive specified.

Answer (score 1):

Some years too late but here it is - [if_nametoindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408409(v=vs.85).aspx) present in `Iphlpapi.lib`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compile a program in visual studio, that has been developed for linux based systems.

`if_nametoindex` is a function that, as far as I am aware, does not exist on windows. There is a manual for the linux version of the function [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nametoindex).

Here is an excerpt:

> **Description**
>
> The **if_nametoindex**() function returns the index of the network interface corresponding to the name *ifname*.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> On success, **if_nametoindex**() returns the index number of the network interface; on error, 0 is returned and *errno* is set appropriately.

Comment: Thanx mate!! The code used this function to enter the value of sin6_scope_id. Is there any way so that i can enter the value of sin6_scope_id without using this function in windows. 
P.S. - The code has support for both windows and linux with Linux_enabled or Windows_enabled Macros. And the above line of code was in windows part.